# how to get value from chrome.storage.local in Google Chrome extension develop code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage

I am using this code to get `chrome.storage.local` value:

```
function getCachedAuthToken(times){
    var cachedToken = "";
    if(times > 3){
        return "";
    }
    chrome.storage.local.get('cruiseToken', (result) => {
        if (result.cruiseToken) {
            console.log("token:" + result.cruiseToken);
            cachedToken = result.cruiseToken;
            return result.cruiseToken;
        } else {
            console.log("token:wwwww");
            fetchAuthToken("+8615683761628","12345678");
            ++times;
            getCachedAuthToken(times);
        }
    });
    console.log("cachedToken:" + cachedToken);
    return cachedToken;
}
```

now I am sure the `result.cruiseToken` have a string value. But the outer `cachedToken`  value is always "". what should I do get the inner value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `cachedToken = result.cruiseToken;` by  `cachedToken=JSON.stringify(obj);`
And make sure you define it in the manifest:

```
    "permissions": [
      "unlimitedStorage", 
      "clipboardRead", 
      "clipboardWrite", 
      "nativeMessaging" , 
      "storage"
    ],
```

Comment: the cachedToken still "", `tokenstringify:{"cruiseToken":"eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNyJ9.9416ae3e26f5fc0d1fabbeffd93a3e42c3fba18a16174927846068fb30"}` @zoldxk

Comment: Yes, I aready have permission to using storage, I am sure @zoldxk